# MEAN-Stack MongoDB Sub Array Delete - Works in IDE, not in API

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I have a `[user]` document stored that contains a nested sub-array `[profiles],[favorites]`.  I am simply trying to `delete($pull)` a favorites from a given profile based on the favorites name.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("558d53eebdd9804820090fa1"),    
"name" : "Frank",
"email" : "Frank@FrankTheTank.com",   
"profiles" : [ 
    {
        "avatar" : "div-male",
        "age" : "35",
        "gender" : "Male",
        "profilename" : "Oly Lifter",
        "_id" : ObjectId("558d5404bdd9804820090fa2"),
        "favorites" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "Power Clean"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Hang Clean"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Clean and Jerk"
            }
        ],
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-06-26T13:30:44.661Z")
    }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-06-26T13:30:22.884Z"),
    "role" : "user",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Using a MongoDB IDE [robomongo](http://robomongo.org/), I'm able to successfully remove a favorite item from a known User and Profile ID using this

```
 db.users.update($find: {
        'profiles': {
            'profiles._id': ObjectId("558d5404bdd9804820090fa2")
        },
        {
            $pull: {
                'profiles.$.favorites': {
                    'name': 'Hang Clean'
                }
            }
        })
```

However, when I call from my server API using the following syntax, I receive an error, note `req.body._id = "558d5404bdd9804820090fa2"` and `req.body.favorites.name = "Hang Clean"`

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(_user._id, {
    'profiles._id': req.body._id
    }, {
    $pull: {
        'profiles.$.favorites': {
            'name': req.body.favorites.name
        }
    }
    }, {
    safe: true,
    upsert: true
    },
    function(err, model) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send('Error Deleting Profile');
    }
    return res.status(200).send('Profile Deleted!');
    });
```

Comment: { [MongoError: exception: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: profiles.$.favorites]
  name: 'MongoError',
  errmsg: 'exception: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: profiles.$.favorites',
  code: 16836,
  ok: 0 }

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact schema, it seems rather unclear what the actual document is as you have a top level `user` key on the document?

Comment: Done, that's exactly how it reads in robomongo's document editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating using the **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)** method since you are supplying the **[`findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)** method with the wrong parameters: the second argument `{ 'profiles._id': req.body._id }`  should be part of the first query object hence you need to use the **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)** method as follows, making sure you convert the string ids into ObjectId's:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_user._id),
    profileId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body._id),
    query = {
        "_id": id,
        "profiles._id": profileId 
    },
    update = {
        "$pull": { 
            "profiles.$.favorites": { "name": req.body.favorites.name }
        }
    },
    options = { "multi": true, "upsert": true };

User.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, model) {
     if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send('Error Deleting Profile');
     }
     return res.status(200).send('Profile Deleted!');       
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Also like the argument structure, much more readable.

Comment: @CampbellGolf No worries!!